# how to set screen shots for my deb file in ubuntu software center

Tags: software-center, package-management

I'm developed an application and also created deb package of that application. when I install this deb file, it was opened in Ubuntu software center and installed.

But at the time of installation, screen shots was empty in Ubuntu software center. what wrong with the creation of deb file or any other possibility was there?

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the second step of the publish guide, you need to provide the screenshots and icons for your application:

> ### Prepare your application icons and screenshots
>
> You only need to upload a 64x64 pixel icon, but your app will be more likely to be seen and downloaded if you pay special attention to this step. Make sure you include a representative screenshot and the full range of icon sizes.

- http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/